# Bootcamp on Macbook Pro 16"

Tags: macbook-pro, boot-camp, overheating

**Question** : Is the new macbook pro 16" any good with Boot-Camp and Win 10 ?

**Background**

Owner of a macbook pro 15" 2018 and working with Visual Studio on a Boot-Camp'ed Windows 10, i have a lot of issue with thermals.
Almost every action triggers a lot of heat hence the fans hence the noise.

What about the new macbook pro 16" and its revamped internals ? Has anyone tested it with Boot-Camp? Is it heating as much as the old one ?

Thanks

Comment: A bit early to know but if it is like earlier MBP then [Throttlestop](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/) helps a lot.  I can always undervolt by at least 125mv.

Answer (score 0):

I had bought the 15" MacBook Pro two weeks ago, then exchanged it for the 16 inch MacBook Pro last week. Having used very demanding applications on both computers I have seen notable improvements with the 16" MacBook Pro's cooling system. Overall I would highly recommend upgrading to the 16".

Regarding bootcamp though, the 16" does have a major problem right now. The bootcamp drivers in Catalina have not yet been updated for the 16" model, so you can not use bootcamp with this computer yet. Apple is now aware of this issue and is trying to fix it though, so in a week or two expect it to be fixed in the next update.

This is a temporary issue, the 16" is still an amazing computer and a major improvement over the 15" model. I would upgrade but wait until it is confirmed that the bootcamp issue has been solved.

Comment: "Apple is now aware of this issue and is trying to fix it though, so in a week or two expect it to be fixed in the next update"

Is this an official statement? When I contacted support about the Boot Camp issues on my 16 inch MBP last night, they sounded rather clueless about it.